# Transparently fallback writing to local disk when CIFS mount is down?

Tags: linux, cifs

I have a CIFS share that is recording data 24/7 and would like files written to it to be saved locally if the network goes down and the share hangs.

Is there any way to do this? I don't have the ability to modify the binaries writing the files.

Before the CIFS is mounted the files get written to the underlying directory, but once it's mounted they will fail if the network is down.  I don't mind if I have to manually retrieve the files later, as long as the directory continues to accept files.

The system writes to temporary files, then renamed them to another sub-folder when done, so that restricts a lot of mirroring tricks with hardlinks and the like.

Comment: soiunds like overlayfs + pushing files from the top to the bottom file system periodically or something